# How Join() works with allOf() method and what is the difference when we use it with single CompletableFuture Object

Tags: java, parallel-processing, completable-future

I need to understand below code.
`join()` method is called from two different place.
what is the impact of second join method.
can we combine it in one join methods and get the result in list.

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureList.size()])).join();
  for(CompletableFuture c: futureList){
     processedDtoIdList.add((Long)c.join());
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats your current understanding of it and what is it that you dont understand? Have you tried reading the javadocs?

Comment: as per the javadocs `allOf(CompletablFuture<T>...)` would return a CompletableFuture<Void> that is completed when all of the given futures are completed. `join()` will return the result when complete or throw an exception if completed exceptionally. Based on that draw your conclusions on what your code should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the second `.join` call is only there to fetch the actual values from the `CompletableFuture` objects in the already completed list of futures.

The `join` call on `CompletableFuture.allOf` will wait for all the futures to complete.  The `join` call on each individual future in the `for` loop will be called on a future that is guaranteed to have completed, and so will just return the value immediately without waiting.

It seems that this method may be easier to understand if it was rewritten to make this fact explicit, using [`Future.resultNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#resultNow()) instead of [`CompletableFuture.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()):

```java
CompletableFuture.allOf(
        futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureList.size()])).join();

for(CompletableFuture c: futureList){
   processedDtoIdList.add((Long)c.resultNow());
}
```

Alternatively, the use of `CompletableFuture.allOf` appears to be redundant here, as the individual futures can be joined on and added to the list as they're completed:

```java
for(CompletableFuture c: futureList){
   processedDtoIdList.add((Long)c.join());
}
```

## Javadocs

### [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...))

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete.
>
> […]
>
> Among the applications of this method is to await completion of a set of independent CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in: `CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3).join();`.

### [`CompletableFuture.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join())

> Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked) exception if completed exceptionally.

### [`Future.resultNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#resultNow())

> Returns the computed result, without waiting.
>
> This method is for cases where the caller knows that the task has already completed successfully, for example when filtering a stream of Future objects for the successful tasks and using a mapping operation to obtain a stream of results.
>
> **Throws:**
> [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) - if the task has not completed or the task did not complete with a result

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I was confused with the second `Join()` method, I thought it would re-execute the task and will wait for each future. Also `resultNow()` is of Future class so I guess it will not work here.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` implements `Future`, so `resultNow()` will work if you’re using Java 19 or newer. Side note: do not pre-size the array passed to `toArray`. Just use `toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))` This is simpler, more robust, and [even more efficient](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)

Comment: @Holger Oh yeah, didn't notice how new `resultNow()` was.  They could be legitimately using `join` just because it was written before the latest versions of Java.

Comment: @Holger I'd probably use the Java 11 [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) version myself: `toArray(ComplatableFuture[]::new)`.

Comment: Yes, when you’re using Java 11+, you can use `toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)` which is symmetric with the `Stream` API and uses the more efficient variant under the hood anyway. Judging from Stackoverflow questions, it seems a lot of developers do not realize that `allOf(…).join()` is not necessary when calling `join()` on every future anyway. A different case would be `allOf(…).thenApply(_ -> /* call join() on every future */)`